# Kivy: How to create a widget on_start with with height: self.minimum_height

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I just picked up python and kivy/kivymd this week, so I'm struggling with what I'm sure are really basic things.

I'm trying to create a card on_start, which works fine for the most part, but I also need to set height to minimum_height as well as setting pos_hint (the two commented out lines, though obviously it wouldn't be self.minimum_height in this case; this was copied over from my .kv file).

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "LightGreen"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "700"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.main_grid.add_widget(MDCard(
            size_hint_x = 1,
            size_hint_y = None,
            adaptive_height = True,
            # height = self.minimum_height,
            # pos_hint = {"center_x" = .5}
            spacing = 5,
            padding = 30,
            elevation = 18,
            ripple_behavior = True
        ))
        

MainApp().run()
```

I have no clue how to assign pos_hint such that it doesn't throw a syntax error.

For height, I've tried setting

```
    def on_start(self):
        veg = self.root.ids.main_grid.add_widget(MDCard(
            size_hint_x = 1,
            size_hint_y = None,
            adaptive_height = True,
            # height = self.minimum_height,
            # pos_hint = {"center_x" = .5}
            spacing = 5,
            padding = 30,
            elevation = 18,
            ripple_behavior = True
        ))
```

And then adding

`veg.height = veg.minimum_height`

Which returns

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'minimum_height'`

Everything else works great. Without these two properties set I can run it and the card shows up just fine. It just isn't sized correctly. What input is it expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The property `adaptive_height` is not defined for `MDCard`. Your `pos_hint` just has bad syntax for the dictionary. Try changing:

```
pos_hint = {"center_x" = .5}
```

to:

```
pos_hint = {"center_x": .5}
```

In your code, the `height = self.minimum_height` is trying to set the `height` of the `MDCard` to the `minimum_height` of the `App` (`self` is the `MainApp` in that method). A simpler approach would be to define a rule for that `MDCard` in `kv`. like this:

```
<MyMDCard>:
    size_hint_x: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
```

And define `MyMDCard` as:

```
class MyMDCard(MDCard):
    pass
```

Then, the `on_start()` method becomes:

```
def on_start(self):
    self.root.ids.main_grid.add_widget(MyMDCard(
        pos_hint = {"center_x": .5},
        spacing=5,
        padding=30,
        elevation=18,
        ripple_behavior=True
    ))
```